# Optional characters in a regex

Tags: regex, option-type

The task is pretty simple, but I've not been able to come up with a good solution yet: a string can contain numbers, dashes and pluses, or only numbers.

```
^[0-9+-]+$
```

does most of what I need, except when a user enters garbage like "+-+--+"

I've not had luck with regular lookahead, since the dashes and pluses could potentially be anywhere in the string.

Valid strings:

1. 234654
2. 24-3+-2
3. -234
4. 25485+

Invalid:

1. ++--+

Comment: I find your valid strings strange. Mind to explain the background?

Comment: My first guess was arithmetic expressions interpreting 3+-+4 as 3 + (-(+4)). But trailing pluses and minuses don't fit in this picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
^[0-9+-]*[0-9][0-9+-]*$
```

This ensures that there is at least one digit somewhere in the string. (It looks like it might have a lot of backtracking, though. But on the other hand it doesn't have a + or * wrapped inside another + or *, which I don't like either.)

Comment: Beat me to it, my exact thought too.

Comment: But is 2+++5 legal? It is with your regex.

Comment: If "24-3+-2" is legal (and it seems to be), then I would guess that 2+++5 is legal also.

Comment: 2+++5 should be legal from the description: "a string can contain numbers, dashes and pluses, or only numbers."

Comment: Well, the question doesn't mention anything about valid math expressions.

Comment: If it is math expressions he's aiming for, an expression tree would be much better than a regex. But I notice that * and / are not allowed, so I don't think it's supposed to be math.

Answer (score 16):

How about this:

```
([+-]?\d[+-]?)+
```

which means "one or more digits, each of which can be preceded or followed by an optional plus or minus".

Here's a Python test script:

```
import re
TESTS = "234654 24-3+-2 -234 25485+ ++--+".split()
for test in TESTS:
    print test, ":", re.match(r'([+-]?\d[+-]?)+', test) is not None
```

which prints this:

```
234654 : True
24-3+-2 : True
-234 : True
25485+ : True
++--+ : False
```

Comment: Almost good! The only problem is when you add anchors to this expression like so: `^([+-]?\d+[+-]?)+$` this will experience [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html "Or exponential, super-linear, never-ending") when presented with a non-matching string like this: `01234567890123456789X` The problem is that this is essentially: `(\d+)+` which is a recipe for disaster for a backtracking regex engine. To fix this, simply remove the `+` from the `\d+` like so: `^([+-]?\d[+-]?)+$` - which works beautifully. Fix it and you'll get my +1.

Comment: Your welcome. I've learned that it is most important to test for cases that don't match - that's where most of the problems lurk. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
^([+-]*[0-9]+[+-]*)+$
```

Another solution using a positive look behind assertion ensuring there is at leat one number.

```
^[0-9+-]+$(?<=[0-9][+-]*)
```

Or using a positive look ahead assertion.

```
(?=[+-]*[0-9])^[0-9+-]+
```

Comment: `^([+-]*[0-9]+[+-]*)+$` will go pathological on non-matches (see my comment to Richies's solution). The `^[0-9+-]+$(?<=[0-9][+-]*)` won't work because it uses variable length lookbehind (only .NET and JGSoft have that). `(?=[+-]*[0-9])^[0-9+-]+` is ok but no need for the lookahead - just use `^[-+]*\d[\d+-]*$` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I like the

```
^(?=.*\d)[\d+-]+$
```

solution, myself. It says exactly what you need without requiring any head-scratching.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
^[-+]*\d[\d+-]*$
```

Fast is good!