# Regex to match special characters EXCEPT hyphen(s) mixed with number(s)

Tags: java, regex

We are currently using `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` in Java's `replaceAll` function to strip special characters from a string.  It has come to our attention that we need to allow hyphen(s) when they are mixed with number(s).

Examples for which hyphens **will not** be matched:

- 1-2-3
- -1-23-4562
- --1---2--3---4-
- --9--a--7
- 425-12-3456

Examples for which hyphens **will** be matched:

- --a--b--c
- wal-mart

We think we formulated a regex to meet the latter criteria using [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884014/optional-characters-in-a-regex) as a reference but we have no idea how to combine it with the original regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

We are wanting to do this to a Lucene search string because of the way [Lucene's standard tokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html) works when indexing:

> Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the token, in which case the whole token is interpreted as a product number and is not split.

Comment: I added the [java] tag per the regex tag's doc: "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."

Comment: Hyphens are only allowed when combined with only numbers? So '--9--a--7' would have the hyphens stripped out, but '--9--0--7' would be left alone?

Comment: I believe that both examples would be left alone because the Lucene quote states that the tokenizer does not split hyphens if there is a number in the token.

Comment: So '--9--a--7' and '--9--0--7' would be left alone, but not '--a--b--c'?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: Are you trying to parse an entire document before sending it through the tokenizer? In other words, are you stripping "illegal" characters from the entire document at once, or are you splitting it into tokens before hand then processing each token?

Comment: We are running the regex on the entire Lucene search string, which is not tokenized.

Comment: Can you just test whether there are any numbers present, and then select one of two regular expressions to use? I think that would be much easier than trying to construct a single regular expression to do what you're asking for.

Comment: No, because the Lucene search string could contains both situations.  For example, `wal-mart 425-12-4567`.

Comment: Ah, so then you are scrubbing characters out of words within strings, and not the entire string?  So should `wal-mart 425-12-4567` become `walmart 425-12-4567` or `wal-mart 425-12-4567`?

Comment: In the case of `wal-mart 425-12-4567` I would want the regex to select only the dash in `wal-mart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a single regex.  (Well...  maybe in Perl.)

(*edit*: Okay, you can do it with variable-length negative lookbehind, which it appears Java can (almost uniquely!) do; see Cyborgx37's answer.  Regardless, imo, you *shouldn't* do this with a single regex.  :))

What you *can* do is split the string into words and deal with each word individually.  My Java is pretty terrible so here is some hopefully-sensible Python:

```python
# Precompile some regex
looks_like_product_number = re.compile(r'\A[-0-9]+\Z')
not_wordlike = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
not_wordlike_or_hyphen = re.compile(r'[^-a-zA-Z0-9]')

# Split on anything that's not a letter, number, or hyphen -- BUT dots
# must be followed by whitespace
words = re.split(r'(?:[^-.a-zA-Z0-9]|[.]\s)+', string)

stripped_words = []
for word in words:
    if '-' in word and not looks_like_product_number.match(word):
        stripped_word = not_wordlike.sub('', word)
    else:
        # Product number; allow dashes
        stripped_word = not_wordlike_or_hyphen.sub('', word)

    stripped_words.append(stripped_word)

pass_to_lucene(' '.join(stripped_words))
```

When I run this with `'wal-mart 1-2-3'`, I get back `'walmart 1-2-3'`.

But honestly, the above code reproduces most of what the Lucene tokenizer is already doing.  I think you'd be better off just copying `StandardTokenizer` into your own project and modifying it to do what you want.

Comment: You can, but it's not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

`[^a-zA-Z0-9-]`

Comment: I don't know that this will work - the OP seems to suggest that hyphens are only allowed when combined exclusively with numbers. Not clear though.

Comment: OP provided some additional information - hyphens are only allowed when combined with numbers. If there are no numbers, then the hyphens must still be removed.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: Thanks, I'll take a look and revise my answer.

Comment: Yeah, simple but useful : )

Answer (score 1):

This question is tricky because Java does not allow infinite recursion in a lookaround, which is basically what you need. I've made due with a 100 character limit, as you will see, which you can increase if you expect the words to be longer.

This should work:

```
(?<![0-9]\S{0,100})[^a-zA-Z](?!\S{0,100}[0-9])|(?<=[0-9]\S{0,100})[^a-zA-Z0-9-](?=\S{0,100}[0-9])
```

Just a simple replaceAll() with this expression should handle it.

For example, consider this input:

```
--9-+-a--7 wal-mart
```

The expression above, where the offending characters are replaced with a zero-length string, will render the following output:

```
--9--a--7 walmart
```

You can try it out here: http://fiddle.re/ynyu

Note that this expression depends on words being separated by white space (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc). Other characters, such as commas and semicolons, will cause the expression to consider the two words as one. For example '---9-a-0-,wal-mart' will be treated as a single word.

**EDIT** The last paragraph from my previous edit was incorrect. If you want to include other characters as delimiters, I recommend replacing them with whitespace in a first-pass (for example, replacing ',' with ' ').

*I'm primarily a .NET programmer, otherwise I'd give you the complete Java code for using this pattern.*

Comment: aha, clever.  seems Java has one of the very few regex engines that allow more than just fixed-length patterns within `(?<!...)`; that certainly makes it less impossible  :)

Comment: @Eevee - yes, there are not many according to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind). .NET allows infinite recursion, so I find I often have to dumb down my regexes to work in other flavors.

Comment: impressive.  even Perl, originator of this insanity, never implemented arbitrary variable-width negative lookbehind.  i very rarely bump against the limitation, though; what on earth are you doing that you "often" hit it  :)

Comment: @Eevee - There are other expressions that .NET uses, like the ability to do if-else expressions based on a named capture which can be really useful in scenarios like this one.

Comment: @Eevee - it's really crazy when you have a lookahead within a lookbehind. .NET places no restrictions on what you put in a lookaround.

Comment: yeah conditions are a [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) invention, too, though the syntax doesn't seem to have made it to PCRE.  i'm surprised you don't have capture recursing (`(?R)`, `(?1)`, `(?&name)`); those are what really let you [break out of regular languages](https://twitter.com/eevee/status/276127899050987520) and e.g. correctly parse HTML with a single horrific regex.  at which point perhaps you should invest in writing a parser.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me posting a second answer instead of editing the first, but I am not entirely sure if the problem is to eliminate the dashes in the cases where they are immediately surrounded by letters, or if the intent is to eliminate dashes only in strings that do not contain numbers at all.  This solution is for the latter case.  My other solution is for the former case.

This pattern

```
String newValue = myString.replaceAll("[^\\sA-Za-z0-9\\-]|((?<!\\S*\\d)-(?!\\S*\\d))", "");
```

should do it.  There are two main pieces joined with an `or`.  The first piece matches all non-alpha, non-numeric, non-dash characters, since we want to strip these characters out no matter what.  The second half of the `or` will match any dash that has no digit anywhere before it in the token, and nowhere after it in the token (i.e., no digits in the token at all, where a tokens are comprised of all non-whitespace, or `\S`, characters).  This is accomplished with the negative look-behind and look-ahead.  We **do** have leverage the fact that Java supports variable width in these look-ahead/behind.  Of course the replacement is just the empty string.

I have to admit, although the syntax for using regex is painful in Java (in the case where you have to use Pattern.compile, etc.), at least the engine supports some nice features.  Although maybe not as nice as .NET according to Eevee.

I agree with others, though, in that this is not really something you typically want to do in a single regex.  I don't know your exact situation, but a simple branch to detect whether or not it appears to be a product number, and then apply the correct pattern would be much more readable.